# Android Editable on TextWatcher not appending correctly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textwatcher

I´m adding a Thousands separator on my TextWatcher

Code:

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
    var initial = s.toString()

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(initial)) {
        initial = initial.replace(".", "")
        val formatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols()
        formatSymbols.groupingSeparator = '.'
        val formatter: NumberFormat = DecimalFormat("###,###,###", formatSymbols)
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
        val myNumber = initial.toDouble()
        val processed: String = formatter.format(myNumber)
        s.clear()
        s.append(processed)
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
    }
}
```

For testing, I input the number 1000, and it works fine. It outputs 1.000
Input 100000 and works fine again, output is 100.000
For some reason, when I input 1000000, the processed variable is 1.000.000, but when I append to the Editable, it appends as 1000.000

Image showing the variable Processed is correct, but the appended result isn´t

[image: Image showing the variables value]

Any ideas as to why it´s happening?

I could set the text of the edittext directly, but that´s not my goal right now

Comment: I tested your code and it work correctly, if your problem is not solved yet , please add your xml and more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so the code was indeed working correctly. Apparently the issue was the InputType I was using for the keyboard, which was:
`InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`

Totally my bad

No idea how to make the keyboard so it shows just numbers, yet make it work with the filter i´m using, but that´s atleast an issue I can work on

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: For anyone wondering how I fixed the issue with the input type and textwatcher, what I did was, clear the filters, appending the character, and then adding the filters back again

Answer (score 1):

I've tested you code and it seems to work fine.

You can try to add it to your tests and experiment with that

`Editable` is a `SpannableStringBuilder`, and to instantiate it you have to use `RoboeletricTestRunner`

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'
}
```

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyTests {
   fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) { ... }
   @Test
   fun testAfterTextChanged() { 
      afterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder("1000000"))
   }
}
```